# Failing to put in minimal effort despite great opportunity

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a phrase or word meaning that someone is failing to put in minimal required effort to leverage great opportunity.

Comment: "Looking a gift horse in the mouth" perhaps.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I think that's a bit too indirect. I'm not even sure most people would associate the phrase with that kind of meaning.

Comment: @jxh I like that one, it captures the simplicity and the relative importance.

Comment: It’s a *wasted opportunity*

Comment: @JonLarby I think 'wasted' implies too much in this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a single word, ***squander*** has that meaning.

> : to lose (something, such as an advantage or opportunity) through negligence or inaction
>   <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/squander)</sub>

But, if you are willing to use an idiom, ***miss the boat*** can be used.

> Fail to take advantage of an opportunity, as in *Jean missed the boat on that club membership*. This expression, which alludes to not being in time to catch a boat, has been applied more widely since the 1920s.
>   <sub>[The Free Dictionary by FARLEX](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/miss+the+boat)</sub>

Comment: Squander is a good technical word; 'miss the boat' is captures the idea better. Great.

Comment: @Tom: Thanks. Can you add a sample sentence to your question, and a few ideas you had considered but rejected?